# Unable to launch google chrome v61 in centos 7 using selenium web driver?

Tags: linux, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, centos7

Environment:

- Centos 7
- GOOGLE CHROME V61
- SELENIUM WEBDRIVER 3.5.3
- ChromeDriver 2.30/2.32

Tried running manually running google chrome inside jenkins-slave

```
google-chrome --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox &
```

Was giving me this error:

```
[31339:31350:1003/144118.591084:ERROR:bus.cc(395)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[1003/144118.702053:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(310)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

Webdriver Error Info:

```
Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.4.8-20.46.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.06 seconds
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'jenkins-slavev2', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.8-20.46.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some missing dependencies that caused this issue (https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=60908&start=10)

```
yum install liberation-mono-fonts liberation-narrow-fonts liberation-sans-fonts liberation-serif-fonts
```

Installing above packages solved the problem!

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

...implies that *you have no setuid sandbox* in your system, hence the program was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

### Solution

As you are seeing the error even with configuring `--no-sandbox` and `--disable-setuid-sandbox`, as per the documentation in [Linux SUID Sandbox Development](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/linux/suid_sandbox_development.md) [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) needs a `SUID` helper binary to turn on the sandbox on Linux. In majority of the cases you can install the proper sandbox for you using the command:

```
build/update-linux-sandbox.sh
```

This program will install the proper *sandbox* for you in `/usr/local/sbin` and tell you to update your `.bashrc` if required.

However, there can be some exceptions as an example, if your `setuid` binary is out of date, you will get messages such as:

```
Running without the SUID sandbox!
```

Or

```
The setuid sandbox provides API version X, but you need Y
You are using a wrong version of the setuid binary!
```

In these cases, you need to:

- Build `chrome_sandbox` whenever you build chrome (`ninja -C xxx chrome chrome_sandbox` instead of `ninja -C xxx chrome`)
- After building, execute `update-linux-sandbox.sh`.

  ```
  # needed if you build on NFS!
  sudo cp out/Debug/chrome_sandbox /usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  sudo chown root:root /usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  sudo chmod 4755 /usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  ```
- Finally, you have to include the following line in your `~/.bashrc` (or `.zshenv`):

  ```
  export CHROME_DEVEL_SANDBOX=/usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  ```

---

### tl; dr

[Security Considerations - ChromeDriver - Webdriver for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101367/security-considerations-chromedriver-webdriver-for-chrome/60111052#60111052)